# Disable "frequent" applications group in GNOME shell

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell

I installed Ubuntu Xenial with GNOME 3.18.5. When I click on "Show Applications" it shows me two groups: "frequent" and "all".

How can I disable the "frequent" group on GNOME shell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Launch *dconf Editor* application and navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/privacy/`. Then toggle off the "*remember-app-usage*" option.

Alternatively, open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-app-usage false
```